# How would you write a regex to match the largest sequence of 0's in a string?

Tags: regex, c++11

If the input is

```
11100011100000011
```

the largest sequence of 0's is at

```
000000 (pos: 9)
```

I tried

```
regex re0("(.*)([0]+)(.*)");

regex_search(sch, m, re0);
for (unsigned i = 0; i<m.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "match " << i << " (" << m[i] << ") ";
    std::cout << "at position " << m.position(i) << std::endl;  
}
```

But it gives my wrong results

```
11100011100000011
match 0 (11100011100000011) at position 0
match 1 (11100011100000) at position 0
match 2 (0) at position 14
match 3 (11) at position 15
```

How do you make the [0]+ greedy to find the largest match?

Comment: I would extract all matches and compare their length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The longest series of zeros is that that is not followed (not necessarily immediately) by at least the same sequence of zeros:

```
(0+)(?!.*\1)
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/G0FieA/2

C++:

```
regex re0("(0+)(?!.*\\1)");
if (regex_search(sch, m, re0)) {
    std::cout << "match '" << m[0] << "' ";
    std::cout << "at position " << m.position(0) << std::endl;  
}
```

Full demo: https://ideone.com/PnFrMq

Comment: Check this input: `1230000001222000231200`

Comment: Thanks mate. I've never used lookaheads in regex before. Guess it's time to read some regex manuals.